# Unable to create REST service in python

Tags: python, rest, bottle

I want to create a REST service, So I tried and here's my snippet

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/plot_graph',method='GET')
def plot_graph():
    #compute graph_list (python object of type list)
    #done
    return graph_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8881, server='cherrypy', debug=True)
```

Now when I enter this in browser http://localhost:8881/plot_graph it gives error

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8881/plot_graph' caused an error:

Unsupported response type: <type 'int'>
```

and my python console says that it is listening but gives this warning

```
Bottle v0.12.9 server starting up (using CherryPyServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8881/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

/Users/guru/python_projects/implement_LDA/lda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py:2777: ImportWarning: Not importing directory '/Users/guru/python_projects/implement_LDA/lda/cherrypy': missing __init__.py
  from cherrypy import wsgiserver
```

Any ways to resolve this?

Comment: I did everything in virtual env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graph_list` needs to contain strings, however, it looks like your list contains integers. You could convert these integers to strings with this:

```
return (str(i) for i in graph_list)
```

But note that the elements of the list are joined together which might not be what you want. So another option is to return a dictionary which `bottle` will convert to a JSON encoded response:

```
return {'val{}'.format(i): val for i, val in enumerate(graph_list, 1)}
```

This creates a dictionary such as `{'val1': 1, 'val2': 2, 'val3': 2, 'val4': 5}`.

For the warning problem, it would appear that you have a directory named `cherrypy` in the same directory as your main python script. Rename/remove that directory and bottle will import CherryPy from your site-packages directory. Or you could simply remove `server='cherrypy'` from the call to `run()` to use the default wsgiref server.

Comment: graph_list needs to contain strings, why??
how could the return data type affect a web service?

Comment: I mean your solution worked but why can't I return a list of integers?

Comment: Bottle supports the following returns from your callbacks/routes: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content

Comment: Because bottle expects your function to return certain types, e.g. an iterable of strings. The possible types are documented at http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content.

Comment: @mhawke how can i convert this list of string to dictionary?
the problem i am facing is that my list contains duplicate values as well

Comment: @Guru: a "graph_list" doesn't sound like it should be a dictionary. What is actually stored in the list and how do you want it presented, e.g. JSON?

Comment: graph_list is actually a list of int like [1,2,2,4,5] and I wanted it in a form in which I could return a response. So as you asked me to convert it into a string, response gets converted into '12345' which is not what I want. I think converting this into a dictionary is the only possible way as I can see in possible return types documented in the link

Comment: and the list may contain duplicate values as well

Comment: So it could be something like {'val': '1', 'val': 2, 'val': '2', 'val' : '4', 'val' : '5'}

Comment: @Guru: you can't create a dictionary with duplicate keys like that. I've updated my answer to show how to generate a dictionary.